# Absolute Value of a Bounded Set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be non-empty. Suppose that $S$ is bounded. Let $|S| = \{|s| \, | \, s \in S\}$. Let $c = \max\{|\inf(S)|, \, |\sup(S)|\}$. Prove that $|S|$ is bounded above and $\sup(|S|) = c$.

How can I interpret the absolute value of a set? Since we know that the set S is complete by the completeness axiom, can we also conclude that |S| is also complete? 
And can someone give me some insight on how to start this proof?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you know what "$|S|$ is bounded above" means?

Comment: It literally tells you how to interpret $|S|$...

Comment: It means there exists x >=  |s| for all for all s in S.

Answer (score 2):

$\inf S \le s \le \sup S$ for all $s \in S$. Hence
$-|\inf S| \le s \le |\sup S|$ for all $s \in S$. And so
$-c = - \max(|\inf S|, |\sup S|) \le s \le \max(|\inf S|, |\sup S|) = c$, from which $|s| \le c$ and so $|\sup S| \le c$.

To show equality, let $a_k,b_k \in S$ such that $a_k \to \inf S$ and $b_k \to \sup S$. Then $|a_k| \to |\inf S|, |b_k| \to |\sup S|$.

If $|\sup S| \ge |\inf S|$ then we see that $|b_k| \to |\sup S| = c$ and similarly if $|\sup S| < |\inf S|$. In particular, $\sup |S| = c$.

Comment: Note that I changed my answer, the original made no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Let do this:
$$s \in S \Longrightarrow \inf(S) \leqslant s \leqslant \sup(S) \Longrightarrow -|\inf(S)| \leqslant \inf(S) \leqslant s \leqslant \sup(S) \leqslant \sup(S)| \Longrightarrow$$
$$-|\inf(S)| \leqslant s \leqslant |\sup(S)| \Longrightarrow |s| \leqslant \max(|\inf(S)|,|\sup(S)|) \Longrightarrow |s| \leqslant c \Longrightarrow \sup(|S|) \leqslant c$$
For equality first notice that:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{c} c & = & |\inf(S)| & \Longrightarrow & \inf(S) & \leqslant & 0 \\ c & = & |\sup(S)| & \Longrightarrow & \sup(S) & \geqslant & 0 \\ \end{array}\right\}$$
Since $|S|$ has no negative elements, we have:
$$0\leqslant d<c \Longrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{c} \inf(S) & < & -d & \leqslant & 0 \\ 0 & \leqslant & +d & < & \sup(S) \\ \end{array}\right\} \Longrightarrow$$
$$\Longrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{c} \exists i \in S: & \inf(S) & \leqslant & i & <& -d & \leqslant & 0 \\ \exists s \in S:&  0 & \leqslant & +d & < & s & \leqslant & \sup(S) \\ \end{array}\right\}\Longrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{c} |-d| < |i| \in |S| \\ |+d| < |s| \in |S| \\ \end{array}\right\}\Longrightarrow$$
$$\Longrightarrow d<\sup(|S|)$$
And this by first result show:
$$c=\sup(|S|)$$